# Firebase+Angular with no backend like (Django) is secure?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a angular website with database as firebase realtime, just worried about should i use backend services like Django to control data manipulation or its okay and secure to use angular only.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase and Angular can be secure. All the things that actually makes your app secure happens on the backend / firebase side of things, not on the Angular side.

The firebase realtime database has the concept of [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security). So if you learn about and understand how to write these rules, your application can become as secure as any other backend solution, as for example Django.